# Query multiple MySQL instances with Async - Sharded Environment

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous

I am building a tool using MVC to run queries against a sharded MySQL environment. The way the current tool works is by letting the user input a query, select their database, then by selecting instance(s). So from this I can build the connection strings and add them into a list and pass them to a method in my query db class. This works great, but will be slow as it is synchronous.

How can I turn my synchronous foreach loop into an asynchronous method?

Below is my current method for getting data from the servers:

```cs
public DataSet getResults(List<string> connstrings, string query)
{
    foreach (string con in connstrings)
    {
        DataSet masterDS = new DataSet();

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(con);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);                    
            masterDS.Merge(ds);           

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            int errorcode = ex.Number;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }           
    }

    Return MasterDS;
}
```

Also, instead of storing the results in memory I will be writing them to a file on the server.

Comment: Look up the keyword "async" and look up the "Task" wrapper. 

These keywords in C# are quite powerful. And will help you get along towards a solution you want, I am sure.

Comment: `DataSet` doesn't currently support a `FillAsync` method, but it might be added in the future: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22109

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, don't know if `DataSet` will like this, if this is thread safe. But this is one thing you can do with CPU-bound tasks:

```cs
public DataSet getResults(List<string> connstrings, string query)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    DataSet masterDS = new DataSet();

    foreach (string con in connstrings)
    {

        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() = 
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(con);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                // NOTE changes here
                da.Fill(masterDS);                    

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                int errorcode = ex.Number;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }   
        });     
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    Return MasterDS;
}
```

Potentially, you might want go back to `Merge`. Only do it after all the tasks completed. If you want to be really sophisticated you can call `Task.ContinueWith`, where you add each DS to a concurrent queue, and then have another `Task.Run...`, which takes from that queue and merges DSs on single thread while DSs are still being populated. So, by the time `Task.WaitAll` is completed, you will be all done